# Have you read my [article] about burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I'm writing an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/article) (currently 375 questions) about tag burnination.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, the questions sharing the tag are not related in any way that would matter to someone claiming to be an expert in "articles".

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it's too ambiguous, and the multiple meanings make the questions lack a shared skillset that could attract experts.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, questions in the tag currently relate to at least five different concepts:

- Help with graphical design for publications
- Help with uploading or downloading a file or files ("articles") to or from a website, including connecting, searching, etc.
- Designing and coding systems for document ("article") hosting
- The `<article></article>` tag in HTML.
- Questions seeking articles on various topics (Please recommend a good article about X for me to read)

Please support my article in favor of burnination. Questions seeking articles ("What's a good article about Topic X?") are likely to be spam magnets and should be closed. Other questions should be retagged with tags more effectively describing what they are about.

Comment: I have read your [[tag:article]] and wish to subscribe to your [[tag:newsletter]].

Comment: For sure this needs to go. On a related note, many questions with this tag are also tagged [tag:joomla]. The Joomla SE site incidentally would love to have all these questions migrated there, but that requires a CM.