# New tag [knowledge-article]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki, tag-watching

I have seen the tag [knowledge-article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-article) that has about 33 questions and I reviewed some of them. They were notes on programming, related to frameworks by [Google Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) (GCP) and Intel [OpenVINO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVINO).

I checked the wiki and there is no information to guide the SO users about the relevance of the tags. Is this tag for questions to be answered or sort of notes to provide information or guide one who might be interested in the frameworks?

Comment: Never mind. It's not technically a tag, it's some article garbage. It's not a tag that you're supposed to use on questions, it's a type of article. I'm only seeing 2 of them though, so not sure where you're getting 33 from: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bknowledge-article%5D+is%3Aarticle&searchOn=3 (**TL;DR:** you don't use it on questions)

Comment: @Zoe It exists (hence the note about the lack of usage guidance), but it doesn't have any *questions* tagged with it (it is a blacklisted tag). It does have Collectives™ articles tagged with it, which is why it doesn't self-destruct due to a lack of tagged posts.

Comment: @Zoe (as a side note, articles are entirely exempt from tag blacklisting; I was able to tag a draft article as [tag:homework] and [tag:untagged])

Comment: @Zoe Actually a search with the tag produced 33 questions but I realized that there are two of such acticles. I thought this might be misleading as to tell  the items might be questions or articles.

Comment: Related: [Have you read my \[article\] about burnination?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397465/1595451)